# Verify and Sign a Jar programmatically

Tags: java, jar, signing, jarsigner

I am new to this topic, therefore I hope I use the right vocabulary.
Is it possible to get the possibility of Jarsigner within Java self?

I need the possibility to do the following things programatically:

- verify if a jar is signed with a certain private key from a keystore
- if the jar is verified: unsign the jar
- sign the jar with another private key from an official certificate authority, which is in the same or in another keystore

In pseudo-code I imagine something like this:

```
JarVerifier verifier = new JarVerifier(/*all needed parameters like the location of the keystore*/);
verifier.verify(jarFile); //returns a value which indicates the result (an Enum or an integer value)
```

Signing the jar should work in a similar way:

```
JarSigner signer = new JarSigner(/*all needed parameters like the location of the keystore, passwords, alias*/);
signer.sign(jarFile);
```

I know that this is a duplicate of many other questions, but I am not happy with their answers. The solution of these answers is in most cases a self-written class, a modification of a class found from OpenJDK or a hint that the code needs still to be written and how this can be done.
This is not acceptable for me, because they are not maintained (or I have to write and maintain the classes myself), I know nothing about their correctness (especially if I have to write the code myself) and license issues.

What I don't get is that there seems to be no easy solution provided by Oracle, especially as it is such a critical topic, where an error might lead to an insecure system.

Comment: Your objections to the other answers don't add up. Your own code has to be maintained too.

Comment: Yes, of course. But it makes a difference if I have to maintain my own JarSigner and JarVerifier, like in the other answers. Or if I have only to maintain the code which use the JarSigner and JarVerifier provided by Oracle, Apache, etc...

Comment: @EJP: My text was not clear enough. I hope I made it a bit clearer now. Bottom line: I don't want to write these kind of classes myself because it is hard (for me) to prove their correctness.

Comment: Why not use the supplied (with JRE) utilities?  Avoid writing it in code at all.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: You are referring to the jarsigner CLI tool? I need an automated way to do the three points (verify, unsign, sign) above. I also considered calling jarsigner with Runtime.getRuntime().exec() but I think that is rather inelegant.

Comment: I think that writing unnecessary code is much less elegant than using provided utilities.  :-)  Runtime calls aren't sexy, but can avoid unnecessary duplication of function.

Answer (score 1):

I try to answer the question myself.

**Verifying**

To verify the Jar there seems not be be a good ready-to use solution. Therefore own code needs to be written.

**Signing**

There is the Ant Task [SignJar](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/signjar.html) which is able to sign jars and it is possible to [use Ant Tasks inside Java](https://ant.apache.org/manual/antexternal.html)

The class to sign the jars can look like this:

```
public class JarSigner extends SignJar {

public JarSigner() {
    project = new Project();
    project.init();
    taskType = "signJar";
    taskName = "signJar";
    target = new Target();
}

public static void signJar(File jarToSign, String alias, String keypass, String keystore, String storepass) {
    JarSigner signer = new JarSigner();
    signer.setJar(jarToSign);
    signer.setAlias(alias);
    signer.setKeypass(keypass);
    signer.setKeystore(keystore);
    signer.setStorepass(storepass);
    signer.setSignedjar(jarToSign);
    signer.execute();
}
}
```

**unsigning**

Did not need it yet.